# How to multiplying two lists sequentially in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, arraylist

```
    var test= _db.tests.Where(x => x.Id== id).ToList();
    var test2= _db.tests2.Where(y => y.Id== id).ToList();
```

I need to multiply the first value in the test list with the first value in the test 2 list.
In turn, the second value should be multiplied by the second value.

Values such as FirstYear, SecondYear, ThirdYear come from the test list.
I need to multiply the first Price value from the test2 list by FirstYear and the second Price value by SecondYear.
The lists are the same length.

Comment: What if the lists don't have equal amounts of elements?

Comment: Equal value comes from both lists.

Comment: The first thing which comes in mind is: [Enumerable.Zip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-8.0)

Comment: The last addition to your question post makes it a rather particular use case, in my opinion. Are you aiming for something like this? [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BMZunP)

Answer (score 5):

Simpelst way is to use LINQ zip method:

```
var result = test.Zip(test2, (t1, t2) => t1 * t2).ToArray();
```

Comment: the values from the test list must be different.

test.Zip(test2, (t1, t2) => t1.a * t2.y),
t1.b * t2.y ....

Answer (score 1):

If performance is important, a for loop might be a good choice:

```
int max = Math.Min(test.Count, test2.Count);
int[] result = new int[max];
for(int i = 0; i < max; i++)
{
   result[i] = test[i] * test2[i];
}
```

Comment: Values such as FirstYear, SecondYear, ThirdYear come from the test list.
I need to multiply the first Price value from the test2 list by FirstYear and the second Price value by SecondYear.
The lists are the same length.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function:

```
static List<int> MultiplyLists(List<int> listOfInts1, List<int> listOfInts2)
{
    List<int> result = new List<int>();
    var limit = listOfInts1.Count >= listOfInts2.Count
                                     ? listOfInts2.Count 
                                     : listOfInts1.Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
    {
        result.Add(listOfInts1[i] * listOfInts2[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

The most important thing is to make sure the loop will stop once it hits the limit. Limit is the smallest list. Otherwise you will receive:

`System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'index')'`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.argumentoutofrangeexception?view=net-7.0

Note: Even if you know that two lists are equal in size, the check for limits is still useful as it prevents your code from unexpected issues (e.g. for some reasons two lists are no more equal).

Usage:

```
List<int> listOfInts1 = new List<int>() { 2, 4, 5 };
List<int> listOfInts2 = new List<int>() { 2, 4, 5, 6, 7 };

var resultingListofInts = MultiplyLists(listOfInts1, listOfInts2);
    
foreach(int i in resultingListofInts)
{
     Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Output:

```
4
16
25
```